# SQL iterative loop to see if employee works on all projects

Tags: mysql, sql

The query I am supposed to form has to accomplish the following task:

```
Retrieve the names of all employees who work on every project.
```

I currently have three tables. The Employee, works_on, and project tables. The goal to accomplish this query is to get each project id from the project table, compare it to the project id in the works_on table. When there is a match it will get the SSN and get the names from the employee table. The query I have formed is this:

```
SELECT e.Fname, e.Minit, e.Lname, p.Pname 
FROM EMPLOYEE e, PROJECT p, WORKS_ON w 
WHERE p.Pnumber=w.Pno AND w.Essn=e.Ssn
```

But this outputs All the employees that work on each project not all the employees that work on EVERY project. Is there some way to iterate through a list of results from the query `SELECT Pnumber FROM PROJECT`?

I really hope I worded this question clearly for your understanding.

Comment: I see that there's an accepted answer. Great, but another way to think of this is 'find employees who aren't in the list of those who haven't worked on a project'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Also you don't need `PROJECT`, `WORKS_ON` is sufficient.

`HAVING` filters the results after a `GROUP BY`.

The `GROUP BY e.Ssn` means that the `COUNT(*)` in `HAVING` is per employee. The `JOIN ON WORKS_ON` is mapping the user to `PROJECT` giving the count.

Use `JOIN table tbl ON .. = tbl.id JOIN` syntax - easier to read.

```
SELECT e.Fname, e.Minit, e.Lname
FROM EMPLOYEE e
JOIN WORKS_ON w
  ON w.Essn=e.Ssn
GROUP BY e.Ssn
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PROJECTS)
```

Comment: Excellent answer, I will have to do more research on JOIN to understand how it works but this works. Thank you!

Comment: I assume JOIN here defaults to INNER JOIN?

Comment: 'INNER JOINS' Yes. That is the default. Its only for efficiency - a `COUNT(*)` will only count those with not NULL (i.e match). Those get filtered in `HAVING`. So an `LEFT JOIN` would actually have the same result. [sqlfiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=572afcd7b7e8cfdc57751a796ae6b66c)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT e.Fname, e.Minit, e.Lname
FROM EMPLOYEE e
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT PNum
                 FROM PROJECT
                 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT *
                                  FROM WORKS_ON
                                  WHERE PNum=PNo AND Essn=e.ssn));
```

You can select the employee on the condition that:

- There doesn't exist a project where the employee doesn't work on it.

You can use the innermost nested query to select tuples where there doesn't exist a WORKS_ON tuple where employee with Ssn works on project with Pnum.
Then use the outermost nested query to select the tuples where the above condition doesn't hold ^^ (so there is an employee with Ssn that works on project with Pnum) for ALL projects.

I hope that makes sense and good luck!